# Duplicated records with Grails in synchronized method

Tags: hibernate, session, grails, synchronization, findby

I spent entire evening try to figure it out and I am desperate at this point.
I have service class in my Grails 2.1.0 project. It performs queries against web-service - queries are threaded. Once thread got the data it calls `synchronized` method `WriteToDB`, which in turn takes a name (`String field`) and checks against domain via `findByName`. If a record exists then do nothing else create a new record.

Now I checked and method indeed allows only one thread at the time to be called, here is log sample:

> Error 2013-01-02 21:29:47,408 [Thread-21] ERROR    - WriteToDB START
>
> Error 2013-01-02 21:29:47,474 [Thread-21] ERROR    - WriteToDB
>   FINISHED
>
> Error 2013-01-02 21:29:47,475 [Thread-20] ERROR    - WriteToDB START
>
> Error 2013-01-02 21:29:47,571 [Thread-20] ERROR    - WriteToDB
>   FINISHED
>
> Error 2013-01-02 21:29:47,581 [Thread-49] ERROR    - WriteToDB START
>
> Error 2013-01-02 21:29:47,866 [Thread-49] ERROR    - WriteToDB
>   FINISHED
>
> Error 2013-01-02 21:29:47,867 [Thread-45] ERROR    - WriteToDB START
>
> Error 2013-01-02 21:29:48,202 [Thread-45] ERROR    - WriteToDB
>   FINISHED
>
> Error 2013-01-02 21:29:48,203 [Thread-48] ERROR    - WriteToDB START
>
> Error 2013-01-02 21:29:48,320 [Thread-48] ERROR    - WriteToDB
>   FINISHED

However, I get duplicated records!!! Every time I save new record I do `flush:true` on it. I don't understand why is it keep happening? I tested manually - added one known record to DB prior to the test and it never got duplicated, however, new ones that are being saved get to be duplicated up-to 6 times.

Please help. Do I need to index something? Or flush something in a special way? Why is it happening?

**[Update 2/1/2013]**:

Here is a code that I am using to save the record:

```
      if(!f) { // Check if record doesn't exist then save, else nothing
          f = new Feature(name: featureName)
          if( !f.save(flush: true) ) {
              f.errors.each {
                  log.error it
              }
          }
      }
```

Also Error sample:

> Error 2013-01-02 22:25:58,868 [Thread-20] ERROR
>   util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Duplicate entry 'Automatic transmission'
>   for key 'name'
>
> Error 2013-01-02 22:25:58,873 [Thread-20] ERROR
>   hibernate.AssertionFailure  - an assertion failure occured (this may
>   indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of
>   the session) Message: null id in Project2.Feature entry (don't flush
>   the Session after an exception occurs)

I can interpret this way (I got FindByName before 'save' part of the code):
I lookup record and it doesn't exist so I am creating it, now it complains about Duplicate entry and I am getting null for variable 'f' which I later insert into another table as a relation.

I think I might try to fix this code with try catch block... ideas?

Comment: If you do a f.validate() does it give you?

Comment: I am not sure how is validation will help in this case. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after some tests and research I found an issue.

`Domain.save(flush:true)` - didn't work because of threading.

Here is example of my thread creation:

```
Thread.start {
    Domain.withTransaction {
         // Doing stuff and calling synchronization method to write data to DB
    }
}
```

Fix was found here: [Grails, GPars and data persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079194/grails-gpars-and-data-persistence)

I replaced `Domain.withTransaction` with `Domain.withNewSession`:

```
Thread.start {
    Domain.withNewSession {
         // Doing stuff and calling synchronization method to write data to DB
    }
}
```

and `save(flush: true)` start writing into mySQL. Since data is written to mySQL, findBy... start returning proper results and therefore I application doesn't try to create duplicated record anymore. Issue solved!

Thank you, Jinzhao Wu, your suggestions helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution: just add

```
static constraints = {
    name unique: true
}
```

to your domain class, then catch related exception in the service method instead of check validity with `findByName`.

Or you may need to post some code from your service method to find out the reason of duplication.

Comment: Let me try, it looks like a very nice solution... Ok, now I don't have duplicates but occasional errors. It seems like once record is written, for a short time it is not found by the "FindByName" but after a few more mites it picks it up no problem. It is a cache issue for sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Not exactly. When you issue a `findByName` operation, GORM will forcefully flush cached data to DB first (Actually you don't need put `flush:true` in save() operations, except for the ones need a generated id instantly). The errors seem to come from duplicated save requests. Checking the code where you submit save request to the service may be helpful.

Comment: @MeIr what errors you got? Try to print all the parameters in the service to see if the request is duplicated.

Comment: Found an issue. Thank you for help!

Comment: Congratulations. Good to know that you made it by yourself.