# Grails - GPars - GORM: Duplicate Objects Persisting

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gpars

I’m having an issue where duplicate records are being persisted using GPars. I have a feeling I’m not using GPars correctly. Does anyone see an issue with this example? This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079194/grails-gpars-and-data-persistence) suggested using `withNewSession`, but I'm still seeing the same behavior.

```
def stageParticipantsForAllSurveys(Map<Survey,List<Participants>> surveys){
        GParsPool.withPool(15){
            surveys.eachParallel { survey, participants ->
                buildSurveyRoster(survey, participants)
            }
        }
    }

def buildSurveyRoster(survey, participants){
    GParsPool.withPool(5){
        participants.eachParallel{ participant ->
            stageParticipant(survey, participant)
        }
    }
}

def stageParticipant(survey, participant){
    Participant.withNewSession{
        new Participant(name: participant.name, surveyId: survey.id).save()
    }
}
```

Comment: too much parallelismus. do the `buildSurveyRoster` with plain `each` methods

Comment: @Bistro I am also facing the same issue, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: My issue was that 2 instances of the app were running, which caused the duplicates. I configured Quartz clustering to resolve